# Rmarkdown slidy increase size of equation

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidy

I am using a slidy presentation with Rmarkdown. The output is html (not pdf). I have a math equation like:

```
$$\eta_i = \widetilde{r_i} - \widehat{r_i}$$
```

I would like to increase the size of this equation only within the slide, not the whole slide.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I did 
$$\large \eta_i = \widetilde{r_i} - \widehat{r_i}$$

or

$$\huge \eta_i = \widetilde{r_i} - \widehat{r_i}$$

and it worked